# How can I measure a qubit on a generic axis on Qiskit?

Tags: programming, measurement, bell-basis, bell-experiment

I'm trying to prove Bell's inequality by following the one made by Wigner, that is:

$P(+_a,+_b) \le P(+_a,+_c) + P(+_c,+_b)$

And that this proof is NOT satisfied for angles between the various axes $\hat a$, $\hat b$ and $\hat c$.
In particular I have chosen the coplanar axes (plane x-y) and that the $\hat c$ axis is the bisector of $\hat a$ and $\hat b$.

So I'm in the situation in the picture [Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewmKL.jpg)

My idea is to take the singlet state (represented in this case by a specific state of the Bell state) and measure one qubit on one axis ($\hat a$, $\hat b$, $\hat c$) and the other qubit on one of the remaining axes in in such a way as to make all possible combinations.

In the specific situation represented in the graph, the angle that I can choose between the various axes must be a value between $0$ and $\frac \pi2$.

Now I come to my question: my doubt is whether it is correct how to interpret the measurement phase after I have created the singlet state (entagled state).

The entangled state I create it like this:

```
circ = QuantumCircuit(2,2)
circ.x(0)
circ.x(1)

circ.h(0)
circ.cx(0,1)
```

Referring to the graph I put earlier, if I wanted to now measure a long qubit $\hat a$ and a long $\hat b$ I would have to measure along x (no rotation for the first case) and rotate the second theta qubit around z and then measure along x, correct?

I thought about doing it this way

```
# Long a-axis for qubit 1
circ.h(0) 

# Long b-axis for qubit 2
circ.rz(pi/3, 1) 
circ.h(1)


circ.measure(range(2),range(2))
```

I wonder if these steps are correct or I forgot something or I can do it in another way.
Because if I measured directly without applying the Hadamard operator before the measurement I would make a measurement along the z-axis I suppose, right?

I hope I was clear enough and that we can resolve my doubts!
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Here is a method to measure a single qubit in an arbitrary basis: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13124/how-do-we-perform-a-measurement-of-an-arbitrary-1-qubit-quantum-state-in-any-arb/13128#13128

Comment: @MarcoGobbo Welcome to QCSE.  You might find Section 3 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.05642) helpful, which lays out a general method for testing Bell's inequality with Qiskit.

Comment: Thank you guys! If I want to make it more generic? Can I use UGate with the 3 Euler angles instead of R_z? Instead of H-gate (x-basis), what can I use if I want to define an arbitrary axis other than x, y or z? I understand mathematically what keisure.akira sent, but I don't know how to implement this.